# Selecting all records from two different tables

Tags: sql-server, select, join

I have 2 tables, “`EMPL`” and “`REG`”:

[image]

I have  5 `NUM_EMPL` records in `EMPL`, in REG I have only 2 of these 5 records, BUT  I have 5 more recors.

What I want to do is
Show these 10 records:

[image]

How could I do it?
I tried with:

```
SELECT        ACM_ACT.NUM_EMPL, ACM_EMPL.NUM_EMPL AS AEMPL, ACM_EMPL.NOM_EMPL
FROM            ACM_ACT CROSS JOIN ACM_EMPL
ORDER BY AEMPL, ACM_EMPL.NOM_EMPL
```

And more `queries` but they don't work!

Comment: have you heard of Outer joins???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture all employee numbers in a cte first:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT NUM_EMPL FROM EMPL UNION SELECT NUM_EMPL FROM REG)
SELECT cte.NUM_EMPL, EMPL.NAME
FROM cte 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPL ON cte.NUM_EMPL = EMPL.NUM_EMPL
```

Comment: If I wanna do the same SELECT but I wanna do it for a mobile device. **How can i do it?** I tried with the same line but it doesn´t work 
`Sql Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
[Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 1, Token in error = WITH]`

@Dave.Gugg    @Jean

Comment: @Jean The above query will get **EMPL_NAME** as `NUll` only if there is no corresponding values so try to use like `;WITH cte AS (SELECT NUM_EMPL FROM EMPL UNION SELECT NUM_EMPL FROM REG) SELECT cte.NUM_EMPL, Case when EMPL.NAME is Null then '-----' else EMPL.NAME end as Name FROM cte LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPL ON cte.NUM_EMPL = EMPL.NUM_EMPL`

Answer (score 3):

Use `FULL JOIN`:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(E.NUM_EMPL,R.NUM_EMP) AS NUM_EMP,
        E.NAME
FROM EMPL E
FULL JOIN REG R
    ON E.NUM_EMPL = R.NUM_EMP
```

Answer (score 1):

A Small correction of **Dave.Gugg's** Answer

```
     ;WITH cte 
      AS 
       (
          SELECT NUM_EMPL FROM EMPL 
          UNION 
          SELECT NUM_EMPL FROM REG
       ) 
      SELECT cte.NUM_EMPL,
      Case when EMPL.NAME is Null then '-----' else EMPL.NAME end as Name 
      FROM cte       
      LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPL ON cte.NUM_EMPL = EMPL.NUM_EMPL
```

Comment: Woow. I didn't know you could do all of that. Excellent @Rajesh